# Разбор bat-скрипта

Tags: bat

Какие команды выполняет данный bat-скрипт?

```
ping -t ip|cmd /q /v /c "(pause&pause)>nul & for /l %%a in () do (set /p "data=" && echo(!date! !time! !data!)&ping -n 2 ip>null" >>.\pings.txt
```

Я понимаю, что вначале пингуется сервер с данным ip:

```
ping -t ip
```

А вот что происходит далее, совсем не понятно...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Сохранил строку в виде скрипта, открыл `cmd` в каталоге с этим самым скриптом и написал `test.cmd ad`

```
13.05.2017  1:06:34,08 Ответ от 172.16.1.3: число байт=32 время<1мс TTL=63
13.05.2017  1:06:35,10 Ответ от 172.16.1.3: число байт=32 время<1мс TTL=63
13.05.2017  1:06:36,12 Ответ от 172.16.1.3: число байт=32 время<1мс TTL=63
13.05.2017  1:06:37,14 Ответ от 172.16.1.3: число байт=32 время<1мс TTL=63
13.05.2017  1:06:38,16 Ответ от 172.16.1.3: число байт=32 время<1мс TTL=63
13.05.2017  1:06:39,17 Ответ от 172.16.1.3: число байт=32 время<1мс TTL=63
```

Судя по выхлопу и самому скрипту - пишется текущее время выполнения команды, всё, что после скрипта (в моём случае - это `ad`) воспринимается как хост, который надо пинговать, всё записывается в текущий каталог в тектовый файл `pings.txt` и сам скрипт выполняется до тех пор, пока его не завершат любым сопособом.